# Google Chrome: How to determine which window has generated WebRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have wrote chome extension, that processing all requests in the browser:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyExtension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "All requests are under control!",
   "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "http://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  function(details) {
  console.log(details);
  console.log(chrome.tabs.getCurrent());

  },
   {urls: ["http://*/*"],
   types: ["image"]});
```

But now, I want to know, which page (tab?) has created this request?

for example:

```
Request 1 - generated by google.com page,
Request 2 - generated by stackoverflow.com.
```

How can I solve this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will fetch tab\page details Who has generated Web Request.

`onCompleted Listener` has a **tabId** property which identifies tab, and you can retrieve all details of the tab.

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(

function (details) {
    chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, function (tab) {
        console.log("This  " + JSON.stringify(details) + " Web request is from this " + tab.id + " tab and its details are" + JSON.stringify(tab));
    });
}, {
    urls: ["http://*/*"],
    types: ["image"]
});
```

## Sample Output

```
This  {"frameId":0,"fromCache":true,"ip":"74.125.236.63","method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"563","statusCode":200,"statusLine":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK","tabId":64,"timeStamp":1359389270317.956,"type":"image","url":"http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png"} Web request is from this 64 tab and its details are{"active":true,"highlighted":true,"id":64,"incognito":false,"index":4,"pinned":false,"selected":true,"status":"loading","title":"Google","url":"http://www.google.co.in/","windowId":1}
```

Comment: if I have tabID, can I get access to contents inside this tab? For example: I want to add some div block with the text: "this page send WebRequest". Is it possible?

Comment: @user471011: Yes it is possible use `chrome.tabs.executeScript(_your_tab_id,
                           {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});` as a reference.

Comment: I think, that I can't pass any variables in executeScript. For example, I want pass webRequest.url, but it doesn't work: chrome.tabs.executeScript(my_tab_id, {code: "alert(details.url);"});

Comment: @user471011: You can pass variables but indirectly as shown here `var _code = "alert('"+details.url+"');";
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {code: _code});` Hope this helps :)